# Get rid of segmentation fault by using scanf with or without & sign

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

In this code, I am facing 3 problems. How to get rid of them?

- **Problem #1: Using scanf without & sign**

If I use `scanf("%s", to_find);` without `&` and set *to_find* variable equal to *50* like this `to_find[50]` then if-statement does not work and give me a message like this `exited, segmentation fault`

- **Problem #2: Using scanf along with & sign**

If I use `scanf("%s", &to_find);` with `&` and set *to_find* variable equal to *50* like this `to_find[50]` then `scanf` show message like that
`warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[50]'`
and if-statement also does not work giving me a message like this `exited, segmentation fault`

- **Problem #3: Using fgets**

If I use `fgets(to_find, 50, stdin);` and set *to_find* variable equal to *50* like this `to_find[50]` then if-statement does not work giving me a message like this `exited, segmentation fault`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
  FILE * fr = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  char save[500], line[200],  to_find[50];
  int oneByOne = 0;

  printf("Enter the ID card number: ");
  scanf("%s", to_find);
  // fgets(to_find, 50, stdin);

  if(isdigit(to_find) && strlen(to_find) ==  13){
    while(fgets(line, 200, fr)){
      char *word = strtok(line, "\n");
      strcpy(save, line);

      if (strstr(save, to_find)){
        char *wordone = strtok(save, ",");
        while (wordone != NULL){
          printf("Here are your details:  %s\n", wordone);
          wordone = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
      }
    }
    fclose(fr);
  }
  else {    printf("enter correclty");    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tbe argument to `isdigit()` must be a single `char`, not a string.

Comment: The problem is your misuse of `isdigit()`, not with `scanf()` or `fgets()`.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning or error about that call.

Comment: OT: you need to check if `fopen` fails. If file.csv cannot be opened for whatever reason, most likely because it doesn't exist, your program will also fail.

Comment: csv file does exist

Comment: @Barmar But `isdigit()` shouldn't crash, though?

Comment: @BilalKhan yes, but it _may_ not exist.

Comment: @KenY-N No, I can't explain that.

Comment: @KenY-N on my platform `isdigit` asserts with this program, but it doesn't segfault.

Comment: @Barmar However, we don't know which `if` crashed - perhaps the `strstr()` call?

Comment: @BilalKhan add a check like `if (fr == NULL) {printf("Error\n"); return 1;}` after `fopen` anyway, the file may not exist in the directory where you think it is. This is a very common error, and I've encountered this many times here. Always, always check if `fopen` fails.

Comment: @BilalKhan please show a minimal example of your .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%s", to_find)` is the correct way to read a string. Arrays are automatically converted to a pointer to the first element when used as a function argument, so you don't need to use `&`.

Your `if` statement doesn't work because the argument to `isdigit()` must be a single `char`, it doesn't operate on all the characters of a string. If you want to test whether a string is entirely numeric, you can write a function like:

```
int all_digits(char *s) {
    for (; *s != 0; s++) {
        if (!isdigit(*s)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Then you can use this function:

```
if (strlen(to_find) == 13 && all_digits(to_find)) {
    ...
}
```

I doubt you're actually getting the segmentation fault in the `if (isdigit(to_find) && strlen(to_find) == 13)` statement. Segmentation faults occur when dereferencing invalid pointers, but `isdigit()` doesn't dereference any pointers. `strlen(to_find)` could possibly get a fault if the input word is longer than 49 characters, because `scanf()` will overflow the variable.

You should use a debugger to be sure of precisely where the error happens.

Comment: My guess is `fopen` simply returns NULL because the file doesn't exist because the default directory is not the one the OP thinks it is.

Comment: Quite possible.

Comment: @BilalKhan I've tested my code. It works correctly, you should only go to the `print correctly` message if the input is not numbers or not 13 characters.

Comment: @BilalKhan please show a _minimal example_ of the .csv file and the _exact_ input that triggers the problem. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63629991/edit) your question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky How is the contents of the CSV file relevant? If it goes to the `else` block it never tries to read the file.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know, I'd just like to reproduce the OP's situation.

Comment: @BilalKhan run thge program with the debugger and look at the call stack once it has crashed. This will tell you where exactly the program fails.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, please create a CSV file